# Difference Elder vs Older

Tags: word-usage, word-difference

Why in this sentence "older " is the correct word?

He married the older sister and now they have two sets of twins.

He married the *elder* sister and now they have two sets of twins.

Answer (score -1):

'Older' is an adjective.

'Elder' is a noun, which when compounded with another noun can look like an adjective (with the same meaning as 'older').

Both of your example sentences are grammatical.